# Opencart - How to select the 'Terms' by default on the checkout page

Tags: php, opencart2.x

OpenCart Version 2.1.0.1

How do I set the 'I have read and agree to the terms and conditions' checkbox to be selected by default on the checkout page? This checkbox is shown on Step 5 - Payment Method. I have looked at the 'payment_method.tpl' (Catalog >> view >> default theme >> template >> checkout) but can't figure out how to make the checkbox selected by default.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using Opencart 2.3.0.2, similar to the Opencart 3:
Go to catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/payment_method.twig

Find the following lines of code:

```
<?php if ($agree) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" checked="checked" />
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" />
<?php } ?>
```

Then convert it to following lines of code:

```
<?php if ($agree) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" checked="checked" />
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" checked="checked" />
<?php } ?>
```

just added *checked="checked"*

Comment: It worked, thanks! One last question, if the checkbox is not selected and the user click on the 'Continue' button, it will show an message that you need to agree with the terms but the button is then stuck in 'Loading'. The user then needs to start over from Step 1. Do you perhaps have a way to resolve?